# Same Page Iframes

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm being asked to create a side by side "frame" in html. When content from the iframe on the left is selected, it populates the link in an iframe next to it on the same page.

Additional background: The left hand side is the menu bar generated from Tableau and the right hand side would be the visualization attached. Using target like in the code below hasn't worked:

```
<div id="left">
<iframe src="http://www.weather.gov/" target="myDemoFrame"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="right">
<iframe name="myDemoFrame" src=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: can you please provide any sample of that ...what actually you want

Comment: You defnitely need a ton of JS for this, there's no HTML attribute which could do the job.  And as it looks like, there are cross-domain pages, you can't even access to the document of the upper iframe, unless you're developing www.weather.gov site ...

Comment: Sure the left hand side is the navigation bar in Tableau. When a user selects from the navigation bar, the visualization appears on the same page. I was hoping there was a way to point selections from within an iframe to another container on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you control both pages, you can message between the iframes with postMessage, with the left window messaging the parent and the parent messaging the right child, an example is below:

**outer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .frame {
            width: 45vw;
            height:95vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="left.html" class="frame" id="left"></iframe>
<iframe src="right.html" class="frame" id="right"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
    var l = document.getElementById("left");
    var r = document.getElementById("right");
    window.onmessage = function(e){
      if (l.contentWindow == e.source) {
        r.contentWindow.postMessage(e.data, '*')
      }
    };
</script>
</html>
```

**left.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<button onclick="clickEvent()">SEND</button>
</body>
<script>
    function clickEvent() {
      window.top.postMessage({"payload": "Hello from the other side"}, '*')
    }
</script>
</html>
```

**right.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
</body>
<script>
  window.onmessage = function(e){
    if (e.source == window.top) {
      if (e.data["payload"]) {
        alert(e.data["payload"]);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

### Edit - Pure navigation answer

**outer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .frame {
            width: 45vw;
            height:95vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="left.html" class="frame" id="left"></iframe>
<iframe class="frame" id="right"></iframe>
</body>
<script>
    var l = document.getElementById("left");
    var r = document.getElementById("right");
    window.onmessage = function(e){
      if (l.contentWindow == e.source && e.data["payload"]) {
        r.src = e.data["payload"]
      }
    };
</script>
</html>
```

**left.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<button onclick="navigate('http://www.bing.com')">BING</button>
<button onclick="navigate('http://www.example.com')">EXAMPLE</button>
</body>
<script>
    function navigate(url) {
      window.top.postMessage({"payload": url}, '*')
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: When I replicate your code and hit send, the payload, "Hello from the other side" doesn't transfer to the right. Also, do I replace the <button>""</button> line with an iframe in the left.html?

Comment: I tested it, (chrome stable on Linux) and it worked, I'll see if there's a bug, you copy the 3 files into a folder and then open outer.html

Comment: Ah, ok so when using live preview in dreamweaver, there's no action when hitting submit. All three html files are stored in the same folder. When viewing outer.html in chrome, I get a popup that says "Hello from the other side" but it doesn't go into the right iframe. I appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem, the alerts show across the whole page, but it is send by the right tab `right.html:9`

Comment: So if the left is an iframe, I need to make it show a portion of a url. Where does that url go in the code? In which case, then if I select a link within the left iframe, the url opens in the right iframe. I guess I'm not understanding how your code above makes that happen as SEND is only generating a popup with the payload, not appearing in the right iframe. Can you break it down a bit?

Comment: If you just want to change URL you can just send the new URL for the right side to the parent and change the iframe URL there, your UI on the left just needs to send the new URL when it wants the right to change page

Comment: So I just need to replace [SEND], with the URL?

Comment: Added pure navigation answer below previous one

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot closer. The idea though would be to have the url open on the left too. So you'd see bings landing page on the left and then if you selected "news" as an example, then news would open on the right, but the left iframe would be unchanged. Can this be done?

Comment: If you control both pages you could make your links call the navigate function, if you don't control the left page it seems very close to being able to track users nearly invisibly (IE watch them log into their bank while recording where the click and what they type), so I don't think you can do it without implementing your own browser.

Comment: They are internal links that are created in tableau. For example the left side would be http://www.tableau.com/nav which shows users all their visualization options. Then when selecting a link from the left iframe that shows them their options, like "pie chart" which is = http://www.tableau.com/nav/piechart loads on the right.